# Android Studio freezes entire computer upon pressing 'Play'? (Ubuntu)

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu

Pretty self-explanatory. Whenever I try to press 'play', as in the green play button to try and test run the app, my ENTIRE computer freezes. (Otherwise Android Studio seems to work fine, if a bit laggy.) I can't even move the cursor--even if I wait for more than fifteen minutes, it's frozen. The only option is to shut down the entire computer using the button on the outside of the computer. In my research, I couldn't find anything else with the same problem, let alone a solution.

I've tried installing an earlier version of android studio, but it did not help. Same problem. I'm thinking I might have to do a fresh install of Ubuntu and see if that works, which is a pain because I have GBs and GBs of data on this one. Help?

Specs: Running an Acer Aspire with 8GB of RAM, 64bit, Intel® Celeron(R) CPU N2840 @ 2.16GHz × 2. Can't check the RAM at time of the error, because the entire computer gets frozen.

Comment: What are your pc specs? Have you checked your ram usage?

Comment: I kinda had same problem. For me the problem was i also had Chrome opened with a bunch of tabs and pinned tabs opened.  Apparently that seems to eat some RAM also so i installed this extension https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/the-great-suspender/klbibkeccnjlkjkiokjodocebajanakg. However although this helped me a bit and my mouse was not freezing anymore, i still had to add more RAM to my computer. The main problem was that i was using the debug build variant to build the project with also compiles the tests and my project required 4Gb of heap size for that.

Comment: În order to overcome the heap size problem i made a different build variant and disabled proguard and made the heap size smaller to 512 MB and now is working ok on the old laptop also.  But building the debug variant is still a pain. Hope this helps somehow .

Comment: Unfortunately though the new build still executes also the task for preparing the test environment so at least for me it doesnt execute all the tasks for testing but i still haven't found a way to disable the execution of tasks related to tests for a build variant or a flavor. Not sure if that is even possible

Answer (score 0):

To anyone struggling with this -

My machine is a 16gb ram ubuntu os machine. A new one.

And it took me ages to figured out that it was because of one activity xml of mine, where I was dealing with too many nested layouts with `layout_weight`, `weightsum` and `0dp` business.

It was the last place I thought to look but that worked. So just rewrite your activity layouts or better yet, use the Jetpack compose.